# Правильно передать переменную PHP POST-запросом

Tags: php, html

Использую форму. Нужно передать POST-запросом `id` в `value` с `type="hidden"`. Правильно ли я делаю, что передаю `id` в клиент? Как это принято делать? *Шифровать?*

```
<?$id = 1?>
 <form action="handler.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">
  <input type="text" name="text" value="">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что и от кого вы хотите защитить. В любом случае на стороне сервера должна быть проверка введённых пользователем данных. Ещё есть одна уязвимость CSRF. Это как раз то, что предлагают вам в ответе ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">
  <input type="text" name="text" value="">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Лично я бы добавил сюда ещё одно скрытое поле со значением, которое генерируется специальным образом (токен) и проверял это значение на сервере. Просто, чтобы данные формы не подменили.

Comment: Токен генерировать с использованием [random_bytes](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.random-bytes.php)?

Comment: Да. Можно и так.